# combine data with different header

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a multiple worksheets majority of have same header
but one(1) worksheet has different header

I have this code that will combine them all

```
Sub combined()

Dim xWs As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next

Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
xWs.name = "Combined"
Worksheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Copy _
           Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)

Next

Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
Dim j As Long, K As Long
K = Sheets.Count

For j = K To 1 Step -1
    t = Sheets(j).name
    If t <> "Combined" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(j).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next j
```

End Sub

it works well but I want my 1 sheet to be inserted on column D to it's last column

sheet3 doesn't contains the first 3 columns of the other sheet
example

sheet1, sheet2 and sheet 4 contains this columns

```
Branch | Population | Store | name | age | ...
```

while sheet3 contains

```
name | age | ...
```

the rest are the same only on the first 3 columns are not.
I don't what am I going to add to the code to insert it on its designated column.

oh they contains different data values

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy, and not-so-dynamic way of doing it, would be to change the copy procedure for sheet3. By simply adding an `if` in the loop like so:

```
For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
    If i <> 4 Then
        Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Copy _
           Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)
    Else
        Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Copy _
           Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 4)

    End If
Next i
```

This shifts the whole "paste" part 3 columns for sheet 3.

Depending on how columns could change for other sheets, you could count the columns and shift accordingly, even without using an `if` statement.

If columns are always missing from left to right, and Sheet1 is used as a base for how large the table is (as it is in this code), you could do something a bit more dynamic like this:

```
Dim xWs As Worksheet, i As Long, lCol As Long, mCol As Long

Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
xWs.Name = "Combined"
mCol = Worksheets(2).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Worksheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        lCol = Worksheets(i).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Copy _
           Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, mCol - lCol)
Next i
```

Or something more advanced and comparing the name of each column.